# PEM_write_X509(x509 *) and crash in multi threaded process

Tags: openssl, x509, pem

I am using `PEM_write_X509(x509*)` to write a certificate received when connecting to SSL server. This is working in single thread environments but fails in multi thread environments.

What is the difference between `PEM_write_X509_AUX()` and `PEM_write_X509()`?

Will it be ok to dump the certificate using just `write()` call?

Are there other options to write the certificate file in multi threaded application?

Comment: *"This is working in single thread environments but fails in multi thread environments."* - you could show your code which installs the locks. But I think the questions are answerable without it. Personally, I would work the multi-threaded crash problem because you likely have other issues. The crash in the app is likely just a symptom or instance problem.

Comment: ***"Will it be ok to dump the certificate using just write() call?"*** - that's a big NO. The `X509*` is an in-memory data structure. Its an internal representation and not mean to be serialized. If you try, you will see some cert data and a lot of pointers. You need the routines like `PEM_write_bio_X509` to serialize in PEM, and `i2d_X509_bio` to serialize in ASN.1/DER format.

Comment: yes. I completely agree....

Answer (score 0):

I am able to solve this problem after using the following code instead of `PEM_write_X509()`.

```c
X509  *cert = GetPeerCertificate(hostname, port);
if(cert)
{
    unsigned char *data;
    unsigned int len = 0;
    BIO *bio = BIO_new(BIO_s_mem());
    PEM_write_bio_X509(bio, cert);
    len = BIO_get_mem_data(bio, &data);
    if(0 != Writeile(certificate_file, data, len))
    {
        ret = ERROR;
    }
    BIO_free(bio);
}
```